# Is there a way to query nodes in Neo4j based on "dateProperty"

Tags: javascript, date, neo4j

I have a group of nodes living in Neo4J with a label: Image.
These nodes have three properties. ID, imgPath and Time_taken.
I am writing a Javascript function in which the user can select dates in two textboxes (start/end date) and then on button click a PHP script runs with a neo4j request.
I read that neo4j doesn't support date format. My question is if there is a straightforward way to query nodes based on a "date property". Please note that the date is not the same with the timestamp of the node's creation.

Thanks
D.

Comment: what does your timetaken property looks like? unixTime? iso8601? strtime?

Comment: This is the format:  "Thu, 26 Feb 2015 11:47:42 +0000".

Comment: If you can convert the Date in UTC Unix timestamp, then you can query using simple Math operators. Here's an idea of the concept: http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?608bf0701e3306a23e77 and here we used the same concept for visual queries on a timebar: http://keylines.com/network-visualization/visualize-neo4j-time-graph

Comment: I see. Thank you. This is a quite not straightforward approach on something which is so trivial.

Comment: Handling time events it is definitely something not trivial.

Comment: Well something like this in a RDBMS is ridiculously simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the workflow I followed after all:

1) I used the datePicker of JQuery to select dates.

2) I found all the dates between the start and the end date.

3) I played with the strings and created the query in a suitable form.
   In the query I used the LIKE in order to find similarities related with this part of the date: day Month Year (e.g. 12 Feb 2015).

4) I send the request using CURL (and PHP).

5) Got the results in JSON format.

So to sum up what actually helped me to solve the problem was to find the dates (using javascript/jquery) between a start and an end date and then use the LIKE functionality.

I hope this helps someone. I will post the code when I find some time.

D.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [GraphAware TimeTree](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree), which allows you to attach events (Images in your case) to an in-graph time index and query by time, time ranges, etc.

In the next release (which will be out soon after Neo4j 2.2 is out), you will be able to configure the tree to automatically attach Images to the tree without you as a programmer needing to do the attachment explicitly.